# gravatar in user model

Tags: php, yii

in my `models/User.php` how would i call a widget for my gravatar? Is it even possible / advisable? or should i only call widgets in my view?

this is my function

```
public function getAvatar() {

            $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);

            $id = $user->id;
            $dir = 'uploads/user';
            $img = $user->avatar_link;
            $full_img_dir = './'.$dir.'/'.$id.'/'.$img;

        if (!empty($img) && file_exists($full_img_dir)) 
        {
               return Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/'.$dir.'/'.$id.'/'.$img;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->widget('site.common.extensions.yii-gravatar.YiiGravatar', array(
                          'email'=>$user->email,
                          'size'=>100,
                          'defaultImage'=>'mm',
                          'secure'=>true,
                          'rating'=>'pg',
                          'emailHashed'=>md5,
                     ));
        }
    }
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
User and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "widget".
```

Comment: Widget is a part of `VIEW`. By this, you are breaking `MVC` architecture.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the heads up. new to MVC.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should call the model from an extension and not the other way arround :

For instance in /extensions/Gravatar/Gravatar.php you could make a function init() with the getAvatar() code which would then load the other widget (http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25678-load-widget-from-inside-widget/)

That's the way I would do it : 1 new custom extension to load all in place.